# Force 4:3 in fullscreen mode

Tags: macos, opengl, fullscreen

Does anybody know how to force 4:3 when enabling fullscreen mode using OpenGL and AGL?

Comment: Do you mean when you set a 4:3 mode it stretches it on a 16:9/16:10 screen?  If so the driver (graphics card or monitor) does that, nowt you can do about it, alas.

Comment: You should accept one answer (I've seen no answer acceptance by your profile to every question). Or are you not satified by our answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a fullscreen window, then call *glViewport* with the approriate parameters in order to select the 4:3 area.

Answer (score 1):

Create a regular context at the native resolution of the display and then make a FBO with the desired aspect ratio, render your scene to that, and then use the FBO texture to render a quad with the correct aspect ratio to the screen.